# Remove unwanted Text before and after a character in .csv/.txt/.xml

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

**Hi Friends i have a .csv file in which there are some unwanted text which i want to remove for extracting the files name only. 
So far i have tried below code but its removing whole Data from the file. 
If anybody is having any idea to solve this please help. soultion using C# and powershell script would be appreciated.**

> (Get-Content "D:\Saved\document\document1.csv") |
>
> Foreach-object {$_ -replace ".*>" -replace "<.*"} |
>
> Set-Content "D:\Saved\document\document1.csv"

**File is having Text as below:**

```
    <deployment>
  <metadata>
    <title>TEST-2014-08026</title>
    <date>30-05-2014</date>
    <author>Developer</author>
    <svnrevision>svn://10.285.120.144/devmd/Trunk</svnrevision> 
  </metadata>
  <csvfiles>
    <csv>
        <file>Directorcsv\tcl\safetodl\Spec_typ\TEST-2014-08026_Spec_typ.csv</file>
        <loadCtl>tcl\safetodl\Spec_typ\Spec_typ.ctl</loadCtl>
        <AffectedTables>
            <table tname="Spec_typ"/>
        </AffectedTables>
    </csv>
    <csv>
        <file>Directorcsv\tcl\safetodl\Spec_typ_arg\TEST-2014-08026_Spec_typ_arg.csv</file>
        <loadCtl>tcl\safetodl\Spec_typ_arg\Spec_typ_arg.ctl</loadCtl>
        <AffectedTables>
            <table tname="Spec_typ_arg"/>
        </AffectedTables>
    </csv>
    <csv>
        <file>Directorcsv\tcl\safetodl\doc_lolcation\TEST-2014-08026_doc_lolcation.csv</file>
        <loadCtl>tcl\safetodl\doc_lolcation\doc_lolcation.ctl</loadCtl>
        <AffectedTables>
            <table tname="doc_lolcation"/>
        </AffectedTables>
    </csv>

    <csv>
        <file>Directorcsv\tcl\safetodl\stsmst\TEST-2014-08026_stsmst.csv</file>
        <loadCtl>tcl\safetodl\stsmst\stsmst.ctl</loadCtl>
        <AffectedTables>
            <table tname="stsmst"/>
        </AffectedTables>
    </csv>

    <csv>
        <file>Directorcsv\tcl\safetodl\stsmst\TEST-2014-08026_stsmst.csv</file>
        <loadCtl>tcl\safetodl\stsmst\stsmst.ctl</loadCtl>
        <AffectedTables>
            <table tname="stsmst"/>
        </AffectedTables>
    </csv>

  </csvfiles>
  <files>
    <labels>
        <label>
          <directories>
            <dir>labels</dir>
          </directories>
          <labelFiles>
            <labFile>LABEL\5348_dev_carlbl.POF</labFile>
            <labFile>LABEL\5348_dev_carlbl.lbl</labFile>
            <labFile>5348_dev_carlbl.msql</labFile>
          </labelFiles>
        </label>
    </labels>
  </files>
</deployment>
```

**Code**

**CODE 2**

```
<deployment>
  <metadata>
    <title>Test-2014-01825</title>
    <date>05-03-2014</date>
    <svnrevision>svn://10.285.120.144/devmd/Trunk/wm/LES</svnrevision>
    <packagedir/>
  </metadata>
   <dda>
    <packages>
      <dda-package>
        <library>TCP_Add_Exports</library>
        <package-name>uc-TCP-inbound-report</package-name>
      </dda-package>
    </packages>
  </dda>
  <moca>
     <mocadir>TCPint</mocadir>
     <commands>
        <command>list_TCP_inbound_report.mcmd</command>
        <command>list_TCP_inboundheader_report.mcmd</command>
     </commands>
  </moca>
</deployment>
```

**I want to save result as For EX :**

```
TEST-2014-08026_Spec_typ.csv
Spec_typ.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_Spec_typ_arg.csv
Spec_typ_arg.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_doc_lolcation.csv
```

Comment: why is C# tagged here? =|

Comment: @Seva

Because solution in both languages are usefull for me and with this way i can get more members to help me here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could just do a RegEx search on it...

```
GC D:\Convert\txtdoc\rtbTextBox.csv | ?{$_ -match "\\([^\\]+?\.(?:csv|ctl))<"}|%{$Matches[1]}
```

If you want to output it to a file you pipe it to Out-File.

Output:

```
TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ.csv
doc_typ.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ_arg.csv
doc_typ_arg.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_doc_lblfmt.csv
doc_lblfmt.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_dscmst.csv
dscmst.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_lblfmt.csv
lblfmt.ctl
```

**Edit:** That only grabs CSV and CTL files. If you want all of them change the `(?:csv|ctl)` to `.*?` and you're set.

**Edit2:** Ok, had to revise things a bit, but this should grab all your file names now:

```
GC C:\temp\test.txt | ?{$_ -match "(?:.*?file.*?|loadctl|command)>.*?\\?([^\\]+?\..*?)<"}|%{$Matches[1]}
```

That outputs:

```
TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ.csv
doc_typ.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ_arg.csv
doc_typ_arg.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_doc_lblfmt.csv
doc_lblfmt.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_dscmst.csv
dscmst.ctl
TEST-2014-08026_lblfmt.csv
lblfmt.ctl
1662_ceva_carlbl.POF
1662_ceva_carlbl.lbl
1662_ceva_carlbl.msql
```

That grabs anything with `file` in the node name, and matching a `*.*` pattern, as well as the `loadctl` nodes matching the `*.*` pattern.

Comment: Thankyou almost i got what i want but still there is something which is missing i am not getting last line .msql file using this code please help.


GC D:\Convert\txtdoc\rtbTextBox.csv | ?{$_ -match "\\([^\\]+?\.(.*?))<"}|%{$Matches[1]} |
Set-Content "D:\Convert\txtdoc\rtbTextBox2.csv"

Comment: Hi
I am getting below error while running EDIT2  code


Bad argument to operator '-match': parsing "(?:.?file.?|loadctl)>.?\?([^\]+?..?)<" - Unterminated [] set..
At C:\Users\Dheeraj\AppData\Local\Temp\ef02ab90-4040-4f30-a209-bfbf0fd6ac9d.ps1:1 char:50
+ GC D:\Convert\txtdoc\rtbTextBox.txt | ?{$_ -match <<<<  "(?:.?file.?|loadctl)>.?\?([^\]+?..?)<"} | %{$Matches[1
]}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't formatted right so it lost characters. I corrected the formatting. You'll want to fix the file path at the beginning of the line.

Comment: First of all i would like to give you thank you For resolving my issue.
But here again i am in trouble i have one more .TXT file in which i have Text As **Code2** see the First Post

Comment: I updated the code, but all you need to do is add the Node name to the beginning of the match pattern with possible nodes separated by a pipe character. So `(?:.*?file.*?|loadctl)` becomes `(?:.*?file.*?|loadctl|command)` and it now includes that node as well. You should be able to adapt that for future use.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. Now Just a small thing in the code 2 there is node like **<package-name>uc-TCP-inbound-report</package-name>** i want to extract **uc-TCP-inbound-report** from that node is it possible i have tried below code but didn't worked

**GC D:\Convert\txtdoc\rtbTextBox.txt | ?{$_ -match  "(?:.*?file.*?|loadctl|package-name|command)>.*?\\?([^\\]+?\..*?)<"}|%{$Matches[1]}**

Comment: I think that you need to read up on Regular Expressions, and how they work. This is becoming less of helping you through a problem and more of doing the work for you. Please visit [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more information on how you can manipulate what I have provided to suit your needs.

Comment: To be honest, I have answered your original question. You should probably mark it as accepted if you agree with that, and pursue regular expressions at your leisure.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this forum that's why i was not aware about Accepted Procedure, But now same has been done and thanks alot for your Kind Help. Really much appreciated. I'll go through with your given link and let you know if i'll face any issue. Once Again Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

your text is not a csv but an xml file.
Powershell can parse xml really easily  (i've extraxted infos from `<csvfiles>` to `</csvfiles>` ) :

```
[xml]$file=Get-Content D:\Convert\txtdoc\rtbTextBox.csv
$file.csvfiles.csv | foreach { $_.file+"   ---->>  "+$_.loadCtl }
```

will output

```
load\hcl\safetoload\doc_typ\TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ.csv   ---->>  hcl\safetoload\doc_typ\doc_typ.ctl                  
load\hcl\safetoload\doc_typ_arg\TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ_arg.csv   ---->>  hcl\safetoload\doc_typ_arg\doc_typ_arg.ctl  
load\hcl\safetoload\doc_lblfmt\TEST-2014-08026_doc_lblfmt.csv   ---->>  hcl\safetoload\doc_lblfmt\doc_lblfmt.ctl      
load\hcl\safetoload\dscmst\TEST-2014-08026_dscmst.csv   ---->>  hcl\safetoload\dscmst\dscmst.ctl                      
load\hcl\safetoload\lblfmt\TEST-2014-08026_lblfmt.csv   ---->>  hcl\safetoload\lblfmt\lblfmt.ctl
```

to extract only filenames :

```
PS>$file.csvfiles.csv |%{ (split-path $_.file -leaf) +"   ---->>  "+ (split-path $_.loadCtl -leaf)}
```

output

```
    TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ.csv   ---->>  doc_typ.ctl                                                     
    TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ_arg.csv   ---->>  doc_typ_arg.ctl                                             
    TEST-2014-08026_doc_lblfmt.csv   ---->>  doc_lblfmt.ctl                                               
    TEST-2014-08026_dscmst.csv   ---->>  dscmst.ctl                                                       
    TEST-2014-08026_lblfmt.csv   ---->>  lblfmt.ctl
```

Comment: Yes you are right it was an XML file and i have converted this XML file into .CSV. I am facing problem in extracting exact FileName.

in short from the below line i just want to get output data as "TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ.csv " not the whole line

load\hcl\safetoload\doc_typ\TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ.csv

Comment: Attaching Link FYR. of csv file please look into this to help me. Thanks. [link]http://www.speedyshare.com/rnzAx/download/rtbTextBox.csv

Comment: **Your Output Result looks Perfect for me its exactly same which i want. But when i am trying to run your provided script i am getting below error.**


_Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At D:\xml.ps1:2 char:35
+ $file.csvfiles.csv |%{ (split-path <<<<  $_.file -leaf) +"   ---->>  "+ (split-path $_.loadCtl -leaf)} 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Split-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Split 
   PathCommand_

Comment: Yes i am using 3.8.0.129 version of powershell

Comment: try something like this : `$file.csvfiles.csv |%{ $path= $($_.file); (split-path -Path $path -leaf)} `

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to parse the data as an XmlDocument and process it via [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) selectors. Alternatively you could use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to deserialize those files into defined classes.

C# solution (quick and dirty version, add a few more != null checks)

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

//Load the xml from a file
document.Load(fileName);

XmlNodeList csvNodes = document.SelectNodes("//csv");
if (csvNodes == null) return;

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (XmlNode csvNode in csvNodes)
{
    //You might want to add some checks for null here
    string file = csvNode.SelectSingleNode("./file").InnerText;
    string loadCtl = csvNode.SelectSingleNode("./loadCtl").InnerText;

    //Trim the paths
    file = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
    loadCtl = loadCtl.Substring(loadCtl.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

    builder.AppendLine(file);
    builder.AppendLine(loadCtl);
}

string result = builder.ToString();
```

Output:

> TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ.csv
>
> doc_typ.ctl
>
> TEST-2014-08026_doc_typ_arg.csv
>
> doc_typ_arg.ctl
>
> TEST-2014-08026_doc_lblfmt.csv
>
> doc_lblfmt.ctl
>
> TEST-2014-08026_dscmst.csv
>
> dscmst.ctl
>
> TEST-2014-08026_lblfmt.csv
>
> lblfmt.ctl

Comment: Hi when i am trying to run your above code then nothing happened i mean after executing Result = blank screen 

I want to get result in .csv file is it possible on a button click ?

Comment: this isn't a complete program, just a snippet. Your result will be stored in the "result" variable. If you want to write it to a file, just add the line `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(csvFilename,result);`